# Angular 2 - Handle click on disabled input

Tags: html, angular, typescript

This is what I have right now. Trying to call the `checkToEnable` function.

```
<input type="text" ([ngModel])="city.arr.date" [id]="city.id+'_arr_date'" [name]="city.id+'_arr_date'" [attr.disabled]="selectedTripType=='OT' ? true : null" class="input-icon-date input-default-last  form-control" (click)="checkToEnable()" placeholder="Return Date"/>
```

Comment: Whats the issue with this?

Comment: @VivekDoshi Doesn't go inside the function when disabled

Comment: May be click is not triggered for disabled. Try `(mousedown)="checkToEnable()"`

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari (mousedown) doesn't help.

Comment: Then may be you need not use disabled. Rather try to imitate a disabled css.

Comment: Any ways, why would you want a click on a disabled tag

Comment: Thanks for the time @SaurabhTiwari. "Disabled elements don't fire mouse events". Found one solution from the answers.

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari I wanted to enable it on click, according to my scenario.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Disabled elements don't fire mouse events. Most browsers will
>   propagate an event originating from the disabled element up the DOM
>   tree, so event handlers could be placed on container elements.

---

But you can achieve it by this way :

**Component Side:**

```
disableTextbox =  false;

toggleDisable() {
    this.disableTextbox = !this.disableTextbox;
}
```

**Template side :**

```
<div (click)='toggleDisable()'>
  <input [disabled]='disableTextbox' >
</div>
```

---

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-disable)**

Comment: @Lasitha, glad to know that :) .

Comment: @VivekDoshi can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52272192/error-error-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-in-angular-5

Comment: seems that it does'nt works with buttons: `toggleDisable()` click fires when user clicks _outside_ the button.

Comment: Brilliant, didn't expect such a simple solution !

Comment: This solution does not seem to work on Firefox. I'm running version 89.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css of an element inside a disabled input / form-field and re-activate the click events for that by adding css `pointer-events: all;`