# ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in Angular 5

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular5

I am new to angular 5 ,Here I am trying to disable a input field based on the condition.

```
 <div *ngIf="isOTPFieldEnabled" class="email-field-width">
  <mat-form-field class="email-field-width">
   <mat-label>  Enter OTP</mat-label>
   <input [attr.disabled]="isDiableSignInOTPField" #OTP (click)="getOTP(OTP.value)" [formControl]="signInOTP"  maxlength="6" matInput required placeholder="OTP">
  <mat-hint [ngStyle]="{color: hintColor}">{{hintOTP}}</mat-hint>
 </mat-form-field>
 </div>
```

After the page load this div is not visible to the user .Once the `*ngIf="isOTPFieldEnabled"` value is meets **TRUE** it will be visible to the user.
And once the user input validated in the **getOTP()** method I want to disable this input field .

For that I have set `[attr.disabled]` the functionality is working fine but I got the error as I mentioned in my title.

Detailed Error :

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'mat-focused: true'. Current value: 'mat-focused: false'.
    at viewDebugError (core.js:7290)
    at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:7278)
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:7380)
    at checkNoChangesNodeDynamic (core.js:10263)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:10233)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:10833)
    at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (core.js:10787)
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (CheckoutComponent.html:159)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:10776)
    at checkNoChangesView (core.js:10131)
```

UPDATE:

```
export class CheckoutComponent implements OnInit {
          isOTPFieldEnabled:boolean=false;
          isDiableSignInOTPField:boolead =false;

           ngOnInit(){}

          emailVerified(){
                         this.isOTPFieldEnabled=true;
                         }
          getOTP(OTP){
                      if(OTP){
                               this.isDiableSignInOTPField=true;
                              }
         }

}
```

Comment: how does the `isOTPFieldEnabled` value is changed? is it `@input` property? add your .ts code

Comment: initially setting the  values as isOTPFieldEnabled:boolean = false; When I want to show the field this.isOTPFieldEnabled=true; @Sujay

Comment: I got it, but are you changing it through another component? like using `@input` property

Comment: add your `.ts` code

Comment: No from the same component itself @Sujay

Comment: please see the updated post @Sujay

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the lifecycle hooks documentation
Change `ngOnInit()` to  `ngAfterContentInit()`.
It might help you.

```
ngAfterContentInit(){
      this.emailVerified();                         
      this.getOTP(OTP);
     }

    this.emailVerified() {
       this.isOTPFieldEnabled=true;
     }

    this.getOTP(OTP) {
        if(OTP) {
            this.isDiableSignInOTPField=true;
        }
     }
```